# How can I modify chrome so I can control two tabs with distinct keyboards for each?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I have two chrome tabs open. In one tab I want to be able to control a character with WASD and in the other table control a characters with arrow keys. Unfortunately, It's annoying switching tabs and I want to control this second character in my second tab, while still being in my first tab. How would I program it so ONLY the WASD keys are inputted into tab one and ONLY the arrow keys are inputted into the second tab, but I can control both from just the first tab?

I am on MAC OSX and using chrome for a javascript based game.

Comment: If both games are in the same domain and the second page is opened by the first page, then the first page can access the environment in the second page.

Comment: If you have control over the code, you can use messaging if you open one page from the other.